# Why does this program compile?

Tags: java

```
public class Fir extends Test 
{
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {
        Fir fir = new Fir();
        System.out.println(fir);
    }

    public String toString(String x) throws RuntimeException
    {
        return "Fir";
    }
}

class Test
{
    protected String toString(String x) throws NullPointerException
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Both classes do not override the `toString` method appropriately.

Question: Are these methods overriden?

If yes, what about this rule: If the superclass method declares an exception, subclass overridden method can declare same, subclass exception or no exception but cannot declare parent exception. `RuntimeException` is parent of `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Have you tried compiling/running it?

Comment: `appropriately` ... they to do override at all!

Comment: @Christian , of course I did. Output is Fir@5e8fce95

Comment: well, it is - see JB Nizet's answer

Comment: @Christian , with due respect, you are wrong. You can replace "Fir" with anything and the output remains same. Check Nizet's answer.

Comment: Also it's good practice to put the `@Overrides` annotation - this way you will always be sure if a method is overriden

Comment: @IanMcGrath I misunderstood. I thought you were referring to override the `toString()` method from `Object`, not the one from `Test`. My apologies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule you gave is correct, but it applies to checked exceptions, not to runtime exceptions. Any method is allowed to throw any runtime exception it wants, without declaring it. You may declare them, but it's purely for documentation purpose.

To answer your question, yes, the `toString(String)` method in Fir overrides the `toString(String)` method in Test. Add the `@Override` annotation to `Fir.toString()`, and the compiler will check that for you: you'll get a compilation error if `Fir.toString(String)` doesn't override any method.

Comment: oops forgot about this rule. Thanks.

Comment: JB makes a good point about the `@Override` annotation. You should always use it when overriding a method, to let the compiler help you catch mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

> Question: Are these methods overriden?

No. these methods are `overloaded`

the original method looks like this:

```
public String toString()
```

Comment: But the `toString(String)` method in `Fir` *does* override the `toString(String)` method in `Test`. So, overloaded with respect to `Object.toString()`, but overridden with respect to each other.